# error connecting to external https webservice

Tags: ssl, https, mule

I am trying to invoke an outbound external webservice which is https. Its working fine in my local MuleStudion env. But when I deploy to test. I am getting an exception

```
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://xxx.com/yyy, connector=HttpsConnector
{
  name=connector.https.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=4670c992
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.https.xxx.comy.yyy', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={http.method=POST, Content-Type=text/xml}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-42999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Exception stack is:

1. the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException)
     java.security.cert.PKIXParameters:200 (null)
2. Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException)
     sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator:90 (null)
3. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (javax.net.ssl.SSLException)
     sun.security.ssl.Alerts:208 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLException.html)
4. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://xxx.com/yyy, connector=HttpsConnector

The snippet calling is

```
    <set-payload value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:mcs=&quot;http://www.cybershift.com/wfm3/mcs10/&quot; xmlns:ns=&quot;http://www.cybershift.com/wfm3/5/3/&quot;&gt;&lt;soapenv:Header&gt;&lt;mcs:UsernameToken&gt;&lt;mcs:clientName&gt;HHMI&lt;/mcs:clientName&gt;&lt;mcs:user&gt;xxx&lt;/mcs:user&gt;&lt;mcs:password&gt;yyy5&lt;/mcs:password&gt;&lt;/mcs:UsernameToken&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Header&gt;&lt;soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;mcs:RetrieveData&gt;&lt;mcs:businessObjectName&gt;SCHEDULE&lt;/mcs:businessObjectName&gt;&lt;mcs:queryValueObject action=&quot;ADD&quot; startDate=&quot;#[flowVars['payStartDate']]&quot; endDate=&quot;#[flowVars['payEndDate']]&quot;&gt;&lt;ns:StringAttribute name=&quot;pqr&quot;&gt;&lt;ns:string&gt;#[empIDS.get(flowVars['eid']-1).text]&lt;/ns:string&gt;&lt;/ns:StringAttribute&gt;&lt;/mcs:queryValueObject&gt;&lt;/mcs:RetrieveData&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Envelope&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger message="SOAP Request to ST #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"    method="POST" doc:name="ST" contentType="text/xml" address="https://xxx.com/yyy"/>
```

Do I need to set up an https connector. If so what do I need to have. Many Thanks.

Comment: Please enable SSL debug information and include the output.  `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`

Answer (score 0):

Generally this means that the truststore you specified was not found, or could not be opened due to access permissions in os.Check that the service can access the keystore.

Comment: Thanks Julio. I haven't specified any trust store.

Comment: I am looking at http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=147713 and Dave Dossot mentions that no special configuration is required if its an https outbound call which is my case and the CA is Thwate "There's no special configuration needed if you use an HTTPS outbound endpoint towards a resource whose SSL certification is signed by a valid CA.

If the certificate is self signed, you need to install it in a key store and configure it as the client keystore of the HTTPS connector. "